# Cache-Control response header not forcing browser to cache

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, safari, tomcat8, cache-control

I'm setting the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` HTTP headers to allow caching of static resources. This works fine as expected on Chrome and Firefox. However, IE11 and Safari make a fresh request for the static resources everytime.

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=31535999
Content-Length:186824
Content-Type:application/x-font-woff
Date:Thu, 21 Apr 2016 09:54:15 GMT
ETag:W/"186824-1461231024000"
Expires:Fri, 21 Apr 2017 09:54:15 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 21 Apr 2016 09:30:24 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Do I need to set any special headers for IE and Safari? I'm using `org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter` to set the response headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was because of "Always refresh from server" option turned on by default when IE Developer tools is opened.